# How to reset RadioButtonList on button click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList with two options: full and partial. The default selection is full.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Full </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Partial</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image]

I also have a jquery function that causes some of the elements to become hidden when partial is selected, and to reappear when full is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        if($('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == 'Partial') {
            $("#ddlLabel1").hide();
            $("#DropDownList1").hide();
        } else {
            $("#ddlLabel1").show();
            $("#DropDownList1").show();
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

When the Compare button is clicked, this causes the hidden elements to reappear, but partial will remain selected. This is a problem because these hidden elements should never be shown when partial is selected. 
[image]

My question is: how do I get the value of the radiobuttonlist to reset to full when the compare button is clicked? I know that there is `RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection();` but I don't want to clear it, I want to reset it. Any suggestions?

Comment: See the `SelectedIndex` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put following code in the Compare button click event

```
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Full";
```

Comment: yup just found that after Guy's suggestion. I only needed the first line, btw. Thanks!

Comment: in one minute when it lets me! :P